# Python - Unit test to compare output for two functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am trying to perform a unit test to check if the count of two queries are the same.

Given below is my code that I have in place. Could anyone assist on how I could perform a unit test in python to check if the counts in both these functions are the same.

**base.py**

```
import psycopg2

def q1():
  dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_details)
  cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
  cur.execute("select count(*) from table_1 limit 4")
  dwh_connection.close()

def q2():
  dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_details)
  cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
  cur.execute("select count(*) from table_2 limit 4")
  dwh_connection.close()
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

*Error message:*

```
File "/Users/PycharmProjects/unit/test_calc.py", line 10, in test_queries self.assertEqual(q1(),q2()) 

NameError: name 'q1' is not defined
```

Given below is my unittest code

```
import unittest
import base import q1, q2


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_queries(self):
        self.assertEqual(q1(),q2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

***Code for base.py***

```
import psycopg2

def q1():
   dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_details)
   cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
   query = "select count(*) from tble_1;"
   cur.execute(query)
   var = cur.fetchone()
   print (var[0])
   dwh_connection.close()

def q2():
   dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_details)
   cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
   query = "select count(*) from tble_2;"
   cur.execute(query)
   var = cur.fetchone()
   print (var[0])
   dwh_connection.close()

q1()
q2()

The above code works just fine, if executed separately.
```

Comment: It's generally discouraged to be testing the database when writing unit tests. This is because you're basically testing the database and there are other state issues that could go wrong between runs. Unit tests should be stateless between runs, and this basically ties them to a state. I'd recommend looking into `mock` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unit test with something like

```
import unittest

class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_queries(self):
        self.assertEqual(q1(), q2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, your functions dont return anything right now. Change them to something like

```
def q1():
   dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_details)
   cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
   result = cur.execute("""select count(*) from table_1 limit 4""").fetchone()
   dwh_connection.close()
   return result
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get an error that says q1 is not defined (refers to line "self.assertEqual(q1(), q2())" ). Could you please assist on this. Thanks..

Comment: @darkhorse: `q1` is the function in the second code example. have you added it to your code??

Comment: yes I have two functions q1 and q2 part of my initial code (base.py). Which when executed separately run fine. When I call these functions in my UnitCase I get an error as below 

File "/Users/user/unit/test_calc.py", line 10, in test_queries
    self.assertEqual(q1(),q2())
NameError: name 'q1' is not defined

Comment: @darkhorse: if they are in another file, they need to be imported

Comment: sorry missed the import function. I have imported the file in my unit test code as updated now..

Comment: @darkhorse: you need to do `from base import q1, q2`

Comment: thanks that worked. However output returned did not give an error message when q1 <> q2

Comment: @darkhorse: it gives an `AssertionError` and prints `FAILED`

Comment: it gives me a message "All Tests passed" though I know the values of q1 is not equal to q2. Could you please assist on this. Tnx.

Comment: @darkhorse: are you sure you are *returning* the result? in your original code you don't

Comment: doesn't "print (var[0])" return the result of that particular function. As I see the output of each function when I run this unit test

Comment: @darkhorse: `print` returns `None`. See `q1()` in my example